# cakephp plugin styles and scripts

Tags: php, css, cakephp

I create plugin via console in CakePHP. Additionally I'm add this line to  my route:

```
Router::scope('/pp', ['plugin' => 'Pp'], function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index']);


    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

and to my plugin webroot dir add folder css and file test to it. Now when I use this script:

```
<?= $this->Html->css('Pp.test'); ?>
```

styles not work, when I copy link from source code (web browser). I get link like this:

http://localhost/Pp/css/test.css

I get error like this:

> Error: Create the class Test.cssController below in file:
>   src/Controller/Test.cssController.php

Plugin works normally when I open http://localhost/Pp but dont have styles :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Plugin asset loading is opt-in

[Plugin assets](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-assets) are not loaded automatically, if you want to serve them dynamically (i.e. via php) you'll need to enable the [asset dispatch filter](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html#built-in-filters), although it's a better idea to [symlink your assets files](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/deployment.html#symlink-assets):

```
bin/cake plugin assets symlink Pp
```

Note the urls for the css file should be `http://localhost/pp/css/test.css`, not `http://localhost/Pp/css/test.css`